# Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin works with Java 1.5?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, coding-style

I wanted some tool which could check all the standard violations that I make while I write code. After some search I found Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin suitable to my requirement.

I have not yet tried out using this. Information about this tool was found in this site 
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

Can some on who has used this tool tell me whether this tool works fine for applications that have Generics and wrapper classes.

Comment: You may also be interested in Findbugs & PMD (not so much style but still useful to run your code through) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080/what-code-analysis-tools-do-you-use-for-your-java-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh Yes, we use Checkstyle regularly in our project. [This](http://markmail.org/message/4xej7mzccj656hsh) proves it works fine for 1.5.