# code metric analysis for JAVA

Tags: java, testing, code-metrics

do you know of any open source tool that can be used for code metric analysis in java? it should be able to integrate well in jenkins. I'm trying to setup a complete test suite for our project that includes coverage test, unit test, static code analysis, code standard check and code metric analysis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080/what-code-analysis-tools-do-you-use-for-your-java-projects Though closed, but still may answer all of your questions

Answer (score 4):

Based on what you need the best choice would be Sonar, it has all you need plus some more.
Check out for more at: http://www.sonarsource.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview) for test coverage. It integrates with JUnits and I have integrated it with Jenkins.
[Klocwork](http://www.klocwork.com/) for code static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Open source : Sonar, clover, PMD, findbugs,
you can also try [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) wich is free for open source contributors